# FFDEC_H264 dropping non-key frames

Tags: iframe, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I am working on a sample GStreamer application to play MPEG2TS Video.

My pipeline is:

> appsrc ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ximagesink

If I pump the data without setting any timestamp, all the frames are getting played

```
videoBuffer = gst_app_buffer_new (rawVideo, bufSize, test_free_video, rawVideo);
```

But if I set the timestamp to the buffer, only I-frames are getting played:

```
videoBuffer = gst_app_buffer_new (rawVideo, bufSize, test_free_video, rawVideo);
GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP(videoBuffer)  = calc_timestamp(rawVideo);
```

`calc_timestamp()` is a function to calculate timestamp based on PES header info

From the GST_LOGS:

```
Dropping non-keyframe (seek/init)
Dropping non-keyframe (seek/init)
Dropping non-keyframe (seek/init)
```

The above logs are getting repeated. I don't have any clue, why is this happening? Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Kranti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. There was a problem in calculating the time stamp of non-key [p/b] frames because of which decoder is dropping all the non-key frames.

If you are facing the same problem as mine, please re-check the time stamp calculation for the frames sent to decoder